# What happened to the Data Explorer Input Fields?

Tags: bug, data-explorer, error-message, validation, json

I just tried one of my queries in Data Explorer, and noticed the input fields were missing. Here's a [screencap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rj2sU.gif):

[image: Look Ma! No input fields]

The following error message was returned in the JSON response:

```
{"error":"Missing value for userid!\nMissing value for str!"}
```

Comment: Which browser are you using? Someone else reported this intermittently happening in Firefox, but I haven't been able to reproduce it.

Comment: No repro on Firefox 28 on Win 7 x64 (one trial, so take with a grain of salt).

Comment: @TimStone I'm using Firefox. I've seen it before as well. Both times for a few minutes after I login.

Comment: Yeah, something JavaScript-related is breaking, but since I can't trigger it I'm not sure what. I'll likely be fixing it in the near-ish future for that particular screen though, since it makes more sense just to pregenerate those fields instead of reparsing them out client-side like it does now.

Comment: @TimStone Thanks. Is the code for that on github?

Comment: If you're asking about Data Explorer in general, [then yes](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer). But the specific changes I mentioned are in-progress in my local environment still.

Comment: @TimStone Good to know. Thanks for your time.